# Modal to be opened after page reload in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my ruby application, i want my modal to be opened after a page reload..

I have tried the follwing code...

```
:javascript
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".minus").click(function(){
       location.reload(); 
       $('#memberModal').modal('show');
    });
} );
```

Please help me with a solution..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call modal after `location.reload()` because the page is deconstructed.

I would recommend adding not using reloading.

If you really want to, try adding attribute to location and open modal according to it.

```
$(".minus").click(function(){
  // change it according to your use case
  document.location = document.location + "#memberModal"; 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  if (window.location.hash != null){
    $(window.location.hash.substr(1)).modal('show');
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help .. But my purpose is to , by clicking the minus button, the page should be first reloaded and to open the modal...

Comment: @Cliffs: I see that you accepted it. Have you tried? 
First part is before the reload (do reload with parameter). Second is after reload (according to parameter open the modal).

Comment: I have tried the above mentioned code concept with some modifications and often it works fine but sometimes after the reloading page tends to be blank without showing the modal ..